# Buscar lo que hay modificar al leer en un archivo txt

Tags: php, html

Tengo un archivo txt que contiene esto:

> ¿Cuántas veces accedes a Internet?
>
> Más de una vez al día|32
>
> Una vez al día|12
>
> Una vez a la semana|16
>
> Una vez al mes|14
>
> No accedo|15

Y en el index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Encuesta</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor=91E5F2>
    <center>
        <table border=1><tr><td>
            <table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10>
                <tr><td colspan=2 bgcolor=CCCCCC><font size=3><b>Encuesta</b></td></tr>
                <tr><td bgcolor=FFFFFF><font size=3>
                    <form action="index.php" method="post">
                        <?php
                            $id_fichero=fopen("encuesta.txt","r")or die("<b>No se ha podido abrir el fichero 'encuesta.txt'.</b><p>");
                            $cont=0;
                            while(!feof($id_fichero)){
                                $linea=fgets($id_fichero);
                                if($cont==0){
                                    echo "<br><font size=3><b>".$linea."</b></font><br>";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<input type='radio' name='voteID' value=".$cont.">".substr($linea,0,-5)."<br>";
                                }
                                $cont++;
                            }
                            fclose($id_fichero);
                        ?>
                        <td align=left bgcolor=FFFFFF><input type=submit name="votar" value="Votar"></td>
                    </form>
                    </center>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td></tr></table>
        <p>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['votar'])){
                $op=$_POST['voteID'];
                $id_fichero=fopen("encuesta.txt","r+")or die("<b>No se ha podido abrir el fichero 'encuesta.txt'.</b><p>");
                $cont=0;
                while(!feof($id_fichero)){
                    $linea=fgets($id_fichero);
                    if($cont!=0){
                        switch($op){
                            case 1:
                                if(substr($linea,0,-2)){

                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:

                                break;
                            case 3:

                                break;
                            case 4:

                                break;
                            case 5:

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                            $cont++;
                }
                fclose($id_fichero);
                /*echo "<b><u>Resultados</b></u>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<img height=15 width=$por1 src=barra.jpg>";//muestra opcion 1 con barra de imagen
                echo "<br>";
                echo "A: <b>$total1</b> votos - <b>$por1 %</b>";//opcion 1 con numero de votos y porcentaje
                echo "<br><br>"; 
                echo "<img height=15 width=$por2 src=barra.jpg>";//muestra opcion 2 con barra de imagen
                echo "<br>";
                echo "B: <b>$total2</b> votos - <b>$por2 %</b>";//opcion 2 con numero de votos y porcentaje
                echo "<br><br><br>";
                echo "Total Votos: <b>$votos</b>";*/
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Necesito que, en el switch, si entra en el case correspondiente, lea el trozo de texto de la opción y me aumente en uno la cantidad de la cifra que hay detrás del texto.
En el primer case he empezado el if, pero no se como ponerlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué haces esto así? Cuando se ofrezca escribir valores de más de una cifra vas a tener problemas. ¿Por qué no implementas una base de datos o, si quieres usar un archivo sí o sí, por qué no implementas un JSON, de modo que puedas cambiar el valor completo según el caso?

Comment: No puedo utilizar bases de datos ni json, solo un fichero que me lo han proporcionado con el enunciado de ejercicio

Comment: Entendido. Si es un ejercido conviene que lo digas por un motivo muy simple. Existen a veces formas mejores de resolver problemas, en el contexto de un ejercicio usar esas técnicas sería más avanzado. Alguien puede proponerte algo mejor pensando en la optimización, pero a ti no te serviría porque se trata de un ejercicio. En este caso, como dice @Niche, podrías usar `explode` y modificar la segunda parte del arreglo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés usar la función [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) de PHP que separa la cadena por un caracter. De esa forma, `explode('|',$linea)` resultará en un arreglo de dos elementos, donde el primero es el texto y el segundo es el número.